# Conjugacy class matrices of SL_2(K)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've these 2 matrices, with $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{K} $
\begin{array}{cc} A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \lambda \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \qquad B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \mu \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \end{array}

1. Proof that these are conjugate iff $\frac{\lambda}{\mu}$ is a square in $\mathbb{K}$
2. Deduce the number of conjugacy classes of such matrices when $\mathbb{K} =\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}$

I did the first question, but stuck on the second one, "***of such matrices***" what does that mean ? I don't understand what we are looking for.
I know being on the same class means being on each others orbit, but no clue on what I got asked there

Comment: I'm guessing it means $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1& \rho\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\mid \rho\in\Bbb K\right\}.$$

Comment: "of such matrices" means "matrices that look like this".  Not all matrices have to be conjugate to a matrix like the ones you are asked about.  Compute the number of conjugacy classes in ${\rm SL}_2(K)$ that contain matrices of the indicated form when $K$ is one of the indicated fields.

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\mathbb{C}$, all numbers are squares. So, by your first result, all matrices of this form are conjugate to either

$$\begin{array}{cc} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \end{array}.$$

Similarly, for $\mathbb{R}$, representatives of the conjugacy classes are
$$\begin{array}{cc}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \end{array}.$$

Finally, for $\mathbb{Q}$, there are infinitely many classes since every square-free rational number is in a different class. E.g. $1,2,3,5,6,7,10,...$ and these are only the whole numbers.

Comment: Was thinking of something like that but got lost. Thank you for your help, got it :)

Comment: Glad to be of help.